# How to make TextField which only accepts numbers in Codename One?

Tags: java, swing, codenameone

Since Codename One API is similar to AWT/Swing. I'd like to get the same result of the code below but using Codename One:

```
    private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

        char c = evt.getKeyChar();

        if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || 
            c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {

        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
       }
}
```

This is actually a TextField which only accepts numbers by limiting input types. How to make something similar in Codename One?

OBS: I want to limit the input type for numbers only.

My code so far:

```
public void keyPressed(final TextField current) {

        current.addDataChangedListener((i, ii) -> {
            if(isValidInput(current.getText())) {
               current.putClientProperty("LastValid", current.getText());
            } else {
               current.stopEditing();
               current.setText((String)current.getClientProperty("LastValid"));
               current.startEditingAsync();
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isValidInput(String input){

    if(input.contains("a") || input.contains("b") || input.contains("c") 
    || input.contains("d") || input.contains("e") || input.contains("f")
    || input.contains("g") || input.contains("h") || input.contains("i")
    || input.contains("j") || input.contains("k") || input.contains("l")
    || input.contains("m") || input.contains("n") || input.contains("o")
    || input.contains("p") || input.contains("q") || input.contains("r")
    || input.contains("s") || input.contains("t") || input.contains("u")
    || input.contains("v") || input.contains("w") || input.contains("x")
    || input.contains("y") || input.contains("z")) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My isValidInput() method seems too long isn't it? Any help?

Comment: Well, from a Swing point of view, that's a really, really, really bad way for make a `JTextField` only accept numbers - try pasting text into the field and see what happens. Any decent example would use a `DocumentFilter`. That doesn't answer your question, but hopefully will make you think more about the problem at hand

Comment: The [JavaDocs for `TextField`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextField.html) might be a good place to start - has a number of available examples. [VALIDATION, REGEX & MASKING](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/validation-regex-masking.html) might also be a good read

Comment: I already took a look at those examples, but this is not what I'm looking for, because those are constraints. Constraints don't limit input type, it just hints on the virtual keyboard type. I'm looking for something like this:
https://youtu.be/9B5ZgItFxNA?t=8m43s

Comment: I'd then be tempted to look at [`TextField#addDataChangedListener`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextField.html#addDataChangedListener-com.codename1.ui.events.DataChangedListener-)

Comment: You might even consider having a look at the source for [`AutoCompleteTextField`](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/AutoCompleteTextField.java) which might give you some ideas

Comment: Updated my question adding my progress so far. I'm not an experienced Java programmer, I'm just a student. I need @Shai Almog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments this should work with `addDataChangedListener()`. Notice that this won't produce an ideal user experience as the virtual keyboard can have multiple implementations and they don't work via a key event since there is no key...

Something like this should be OK:

```
myTextField.addDataChangedListener((i, ii) -> {
    if(isValidInput(myTextField.getText())) {
       lastValidInput = myTextField.getText();
    } else {
       myTextField.stopEditing();
       myTextField.setText(lastValidInput);
       myTextField.startEditingAsync();
    }
});
```

Now this might work without start/stop editing which will cause the virtual keyboard to "bounce" but I wouldn't risk it...

You need to define a String field `lastValidInput` in the class or replace that code with a client property if you want to write 100% generic code:

```
myTextField.addDataChangedListener((i, ii) -> {
    if(isValidInput(myTextField.getText())) {
       myTextField.putClientProperty("LastValid", myTextField.getText());
    } else {
       myTextField.stopEditing();
       myTextField.setText((String)myTextField.getClientProperty("LastValid"));
       myTextField.startEditingAsync();
    }
});
```

The `isValidInput(String)` method if your validate method, you can run any text there to make sure the text matches your needs whether being numeric or something else.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working fine. I updated my question, I'm just worried about my isValidInput() method. Check it out.

Comment: Your method would return true for: `A`, `&`, `א` and pretty much any other character. It's clearly not the right approach... See https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/validation/NumericConstraint.java#L63-L80